# Is there a convenient way to get data from a single column into a collection using ADO .NET?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I need a list of IDs. So I have a very simple SQL statement

> SELECT FK_NormalizedKeyword FROM KeywordSpelling WHERE Spelling = @keywordspelling

It returns many rows, but with one value per row.

I know how to use a reader or a data adapter for getting data with ADO .NET. But it seems like an overkill in this simple situation. I know that if I want a single number, I can use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` and get the value without a complete reader. Is there something which will let me use similarly concise code to get results from a single column in the database into an empty collection?

Comment: You can make your query return a comma-separated list of IDs and then use `ExecuteScalar` - but *that* would be an overkill. Using `DataReader` is the fastest way with the least load on resources

Comment: DataReader is not THAT heavy to avoid it.

Comment: There isn't anything like that built-in, but if it's a common enough scenario for you then you can easily make an extension method for it.  Something like `cmd.ExecuteList<T>()` which expects a single column, casts the results as `T`, and returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

[Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper):

```
string keywordspelling = ...;
var list = conn.Query<string>(
    @"SELECT FK_NormalizedKeyword
      FROM KeywordSpelling WHERE Spelling = @keywordspelling",
    new { keywordspelling }).ToList();
```

(note I've assumed that `FK_NormalizedKeyword` is a string-like field; if it is an integer, replace `<string>` with `<int>`)

This will also work for complex data filling of POCOs, for example:

```
var orders = conn.Query<Order>(
    "SELECT * FROM Order WHERE Region=@Region",
    new { region }).ToList();
```

(here it will assume a direct column-name / member-name map)

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer. No

Long Answer. You could concatinate your values into a single field in your response, but would still need to return a resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Not in one statement, but a simple loop would be:

```
while(dr.Read())
    list.Add(dr.GetInt32(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `DataReader` to retrieve the data one record after each other. Then you can use a loop to fill a collection. That's the most efficient approach since it fills on demand. However, you could  hide this loop with a `DataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable tblKeyWords = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection("..."))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FK_NormalizedKeyword FROM KeywordSpelling WHERE Spelling = @keywordspelling", con))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keywordspelling", "...");
    da.Fill( tblKeyWords );
}
```

[DataAdapters and DataReaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Results are returned as the query executes, and are stored in the
>   network buffer on the client until you request them using the Read
>   method of the DataReader. Using the DataReader can increase
>   application performance both by retrieving data as soon as it is
>   available, and (by default) storing only one row at a time in memory,
>   reducing system overhead.